# Canvas not appearing when using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface

I have made a program to display video in 2/3 of the screen and to show comments in 1/3 of the screen, so I used GridBagLayout; for some reason, the canvas not appears, but when I replace it with a JButton it works. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

**The important part is in the Panel class, the other code is just for guide.**

Finally, I have to thank you by helping me ;)

```
public class Intro extends JFrame{

  Panel panel = new Panel();
  static Canvas canvas;

    public Intro(){
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void receive(Canvas canvas1){
        canvas = canvas1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Intro intro = new Intro();
            intro.setSize(1150, 680);
            intro.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            intro.setVisible(true);
            intro.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(intro));
        emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(canvas));
//        emp.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
//        emp.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);
        emp.prepareMedia("D:\\Crab Rave.mp4");
        emp.play();
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel{

    JLabel label;

    public Panel(){
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
          gbc.gridx=0;
          gbc.gridy=0;
          gbc.gridheight=2;
          gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
          gbc.weightx=1;
          gbc.weighty= 1;
          Intro.receive(canvas);
        add(canvas, gbc);

        label = new JLabel("Hi there");
          gbc.gridx=0;
          gbc.gridy=2;
          gbc.gridheight=1;
          gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
          gbc.weightx=1;
          gbc.weighty= 1;
        add(label, gbc);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have problems.  `Canvas` is a heavy weight component which doesn't support z-ordering, which can effect how it's displayed - just beware.

Comment: could you explain me that in an official answer, please?

Comment: lol, it's really a game of the BTS for my friend Susan because tomorrow we are making Christmas exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, `java.awt.Canvas` has a default `preferredSize` of `0x0`.  So, when you use `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;`, it will simply stretch the canvas so it fills the vertical space, but not change the width (which remains `0`).

Use `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` instead

## Side note...

Swing use "light weight" components, these are rendered within a single graphics peer (or heavy weight container).  This allows Swing components to have a concept of "z ordering" (overlap/lay each other).

`java.awt.Canvas` is a "heavy weight" component, mean that it doesn't support the concept of z-ordeirng, so you may have issues with it appearing on top of components when you're not expecting it.